Facing Problem With System Design (Authentication and Authorization)
So I am a final year university student working on Final Year Project. Project has Web Frontend -Reactjs, Mobile App - Kotlin/Java, and Server Side - Java Springboot and Python FastAPI. And I will be implementing JWT authentication for security.
So while designing system, something came into my mind. Is that I will have to secure Python APIs as well alongside with my Java APIs. What's bothering me is aa follows:

User will register (Java API)
Then user will login which will generate JWT token (Java API)
User then calls Java Services, but to access to endpoints user will send JWT Token in header.
There are some services that needs to be accessed from Python FastAPI.

Question is the token that will be creates by Java Spring Boot application, would Python endpoints recognize that token. I don't think they would, I just don't know who to design this. Keep in mind we are on designing phase, no code yet. Do I have to worry about it, or that one token will give me access to both Python and Java APIs.
